# Grails 5.0.1 - Customizing scaffolding edit.gsp template and others

Tags: grails, field, scaffolding

There is very little reference on how to customize the editing and presentation forms embeded in the templates pages generated by the install-templates command.
I found references about _list.gsp and that this template is related to the show.gsp template. But what is the template for the edit.gsp page form?
In fact, after the scaffolding templates were installed, the templates._fields directory was not even created. Static scaffolding is a powerful tool, but its documentation is very restrictive, which ends up discouraging its use.
Please, I need clarification on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But what is the template for the edit.gsp page form?

It depends on what version of the plugin you are using.  One of them is at [src/main/templates/scaffolding/edit.gsp](https://github.com/grails3-plugins/scaffolding/blob/ce7f1241b7663f351e8d95b0e80e7d88207f6331/src/main/templates/scaffolding/edit.gsp).

That template is used when the `edit` view is generated.

Comment: Yes this is my reference. But into this template we can see:
         ...
                <fieldset class="form">
                    <f:all bean="${propertyName}"/>
                </fieldset>
      ...
How to access each field rather than all fields?

Comment: "How to access each field rather than all fields" - That is a wholly different question.  You should edit the question to clarify that is what you want to know.

Comment: Hi Jeff. Thanks for your patient responses. I'm better understanding the construction of grails scaffolding templates. At the moment I would like to have references to the files _list.gsp, _table.gsp and the other files that should be in the _fields directory. But at the time of generating the templates this directory is not populated and there is no documentation on this subject. In the Grails 2.5.4 scaffolding (for example) there was a form template that made the whole thing clearer. I will follow your guidance and post another specific question about the <f:all tag... Thank you.